# override all in one seo pack keyword on custom page

Tags: wordpress

my code is not working on custom page?
is aioseop_keywords hook wrong?
What is suggestion?

```
add_filter( 'aioseop_keywords', 'my_custom_keyword' );

function my_custom_keyword ( $keywords ) {

            $keywords = '1,2,3,name,or,other';
    return $keywords;
}
```

Comment: I am using all in one seo pack and aioseop_keywords does not work

Comment: I have tried this code in funcitons.php file and it is working fine.